# How to set the Indoorlocation with the here api when obtaining Locationinformation from Beacons

Tags: android, here-api, beacon

I want to implement a indoor routing to Indoor-Spaces on the Here-sdk by obtaining the location from beacons. I'm struggling at the point when I want to create a route with the `RoutingController`. This Controller needs  as start point a Location which BaseType is `BaseLocation`. 
But there is no child of `BaseLocation` which allows me to set the location and Level inside the Building by myself from the values I got from my Beacons. When I look at `LevelLocation` I need a `Level`-Object which has no public constructor. 
From my Beacons i receive the indoor location in form of geocoordinates and the level inside the building as Integer. How can I create a `LevelLocation` with the informations from my Beacons? Or is there any other Object which i can make use of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a Solution. You can get the Level from the `VenueController`.

```
private LevelLocation createLevelLocationWithBeaconData(int floor, double latitude, double longitude) {

     venueController = mapFragment.getVenueController(this.venue);
     GeoCoordinate geoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(latitude,longitude);

     Level level = venueController.getVenue().getLevels().get(floor);
     return new LevelLocation(level, geoCoordinate ,this.venue);
    }
```